# Scheduled task only running when logged in0

Tags: plugin, joomla-4.x, task

I built a Joomla plugin for a task and I scheduled that task to run every 5 minutes.  While monitoring the task it seems it is only running when I am logged into the administrator back end if the site.  Does anyone know how to make this run when not logged in?

Comment: Post the codes of your plugin.

Comment: Are you using Lazy Scheduler to trigger your tasks? And is this on your local development environment?

Answer (score 1):

Like Irata suggested, you are probably using Joomla's lazy scheduler to trigger the tasks. Lazy means that it only works when your website is visited.

You could **create one cron job on your server** that visits your website every 5 minutes to trigger any scheduled tasks you have configured in your Joomla site.

You can read more about the Task Scheduler in the Joomla Community Magazine edition of March 2022: https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/march-2022/get-to-know-the-new-joomla-task-scheduler